# Backbone.js - Is this button and event bound correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm experimenting with Backbone.js by creating a table view, and a seperate row view and trying to add the row to the table:

[image]

I have:

- A Contact model
- A Contacts collection
- A Contacts view (acts as the
  main view)
- A ContactRow view

So far, the project is working fine - except for a button that is supposed to trigger the function that adds the row.

Here is my code so far:

```
$(function($) {

    window.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Smith",
            address: "123 Main St"
        }
    }); 


    window.Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Contact
    }); 



    window.ContactRow = Backbone.View.extend({
        //el: $("#contacts-table table tbody"),     

        row_template: _.template($("#contact-row").html()),

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, "render")
        },

        render: function() {
            $("tbody").html("<tr><td>Look at me, I'm a row!</td></tr>");
            return this;
        }
    }); 


    window.ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({        
        el: $("#contacts-container"),   

        events: {
            "click button#add_contact": "addContact"
        },

        template: _.template($("#contacts-table").html()),

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, "render", "addContact", "appendContact");   

            this.collection = new Contacts();
            this.collection.bind("add", this.appendContact);

            var contactRow = new ContactRow();          
            this.render();
            this.appendContact(); // Just a test to see if the function is working
        },

        render: function() {
            $("#button-container").append("<button id='add_contact'>Add Contact</button>");
            $(this.el).html(this.template);
            _(this.collection.models).each(function(contact) {
                appendContact(contact);
            }, this)            
        },

        addContact: function() {
            console.log("yup, it works!"); // well, not yet
            var contact = new Contact();
            this.collection.add(contact);               

        },

        appendContact: function(contact) {
            var contactRow = new ContactRow({
                model: contact
            });

            $("body").append(contactRow.render().el);
        }

    });

     var contactsView = new ContactsView(); 

}, jQuery);
```

As you can see, I have an **addContact** function that is tied to the click event of the "Add Contact" button that is being appended to a div element on the main page during the render process.

I'm attempting to write log messages to the console, but the button doesn't seem to be firing off the method and I can't figure out why.

It's the end of the day and my brain is fried so I'd appreciate any pointers on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example. I updated the code with best practices for using Backbone.

Notice I didn't add the button through a Backbone view. The button is part of the html body, and I just subscribe to its click event and then add a contact to the contacts collection.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.3/backbone-min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(function() {
        //initialize the contacts collection and add some contacts
        contacts = new Contacts();
        contacts.add(new Contact());
        contacts.add(new Contact());

        //only need to render the ContactsView once
        var view = new ContactsView({ collection: contacts });
        $("body").append(view.render().el);

        //adding a contact to the contacts list when the
        //button is clicked
        $("#add-contact").click(function() {
          contacts.add(new Contact());
        });
      });

      Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
          first_name: "John",
          last_name: "Smith",
          address: "123 Main St"
        }
      }); 

      Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Contact
      }); 

      ContactRow = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
          _.bindAll(this, "render");
          this.template = _.template($("#contact-row").html());
        },

        //every backbone view has a tagName. the default tagName is 'div'
        //we're changing it to a table row
        tagName: 'tr',

        render: function() {
          $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
          return this;
        }
      }); 

      ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({        
        initialize: function() {
          _.bindAll(this, "render");
          this.headerTemplate = $("#contacts-table-header").html();
          this.collection.bind("add", this.renderContact, this);
        },

        //the ContactsView element will be a table
        tagName: 'table',

        render: function() {
          $(this.el).html(this.headerTemplate);

          this.collection.each(function(contact) {
            this.renderContact(contact);
          }, this);

          return this;
        },

        renderContact: function(contact) {
          var contactView = new ContactRow({ model: contact });
          $(this.el).append(contactView.render().el);
        }
      });

    </script>

    <script type='text/template' id='contact-row'>
      <td><%= first_name %></td>
      <td><%= last_name %></td>
      <td><%= address %></td>
    </script>

    <script type='text/template' id='contacts-table-header'>
      <thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </thead>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="add-contact">Add Contact</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you, this will definitely give me something to study.  One question, why define the model when the instance is created and not in the definition?

Comment: @PhillipKregg I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Never mind, I see now that the function is passing in an instance of the model.  I was looking at it wrong.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're appending`<button id='contact'>` ***after*** backbone has traversed your event collection.

When you create a backbone view [delegateEvents](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) is called behind the scenes. This is where backbone looks at your events hash and wires everything up. To fix Either:

- append `<button id='contact'>` before creating the view

  or
- or manually call backbone's `delegateEvents` after rendering

So your render function may look like:

```
render: function() {
    $("#button-container").append("<button id='add_contact'>Add Contact</button>");
    $(this.el).html(this.template);
    this.delegateEvents(); // re-wire events matching selectors in the event hash
    _(this.collection.models).each(function(contact) {
        appendContact(contact);
    }, this)
    return this; // you should also do this so you can chain         
},
```

**Update:**

It seems odd that you'd have to manually call `delegateEvents`. It could also be that `#button-contianer` isn't a child of the view's `el`. All of the selectors in that event hash are scoped to `el`, so if `#button-contianer` isn't a child of it the `button#add_contact` selector will never find anything. As a proof of concept, try this: in your render method:

```
render: function() {
  console.log($(this.el).find("button#add_contact").length) // get anything?
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I tried your code, but the button still does not seem to be triggering the event.  I also put the button in the initialize function, and I even pulled it out of the javascript and put it directly in the DOM to make sure it loaded before the script.  Still no luck.  Could I be missing something else?

Comment: If you add it directly to the dom your selector won't work. If backbone works as I expect, all those selectors should be relative to the view's el. It also seems odd that you'd have to call delegate events specifically. I've updated my answer to show one more possible thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
        _(this.collection.models).each(function(contact) {
            appendContact(contact);
        }, this)
```

This code won't work, because you don't have a variable named `appendContact`. Should be:

```
        _(this.collection.models).each(this.appendContact(contact), this);
```