# Is it possible to trigger an event when initializing a model?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

In a backbone model, is it possible to trigger an event in the initialize function, for a nested view? I based my current code off this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523075/2345124 and have updated it for backbone 1.0.0. Here is my initialize function, for a Model:

```
var Edit = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.trigger('marquee:add');

        this.on('change', function(){
            this.trigger('marquee:add');
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to call a method renderMarquee when the model is initialized:

```
var EditRow = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);   // works
        this.listenTo(this.model, "marquee:add", this.renderMarquee);  // only called when changed, but not when initially created
    ...
}
```

renderMarquee *IS* called when the model is changed, but not when it is initialized. 'change' events work as expected (this.render is called). Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make a lot of sense because you are initializing the model somewhere prior to doing the `view.listenTo` call. Unfortunately, you don't really have a choice in that matter.

You are probably going to want to move the event handling to a `Backbone.Collection` which already has built in events you can listen on for adding/removing.

Comment: Oh - I see what you are saying - I knew it was something simple. I tried listening to the collection 'add' event - but ended up with some unexpected behavior. Will look closer at that to see what was going on (every time I added a model to the collection the 'add' event was called for each model in the collection).

Answer (score 1):

I am currently facing a similar problem. I needed to trigger the change event in the initialize method of my model. 
I looked into the backbone code which revealed why this is not happening:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    ...
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments); 
  };
```

the `set` is executed before the `initialize` and `this.change` is emptied setting the model state to "nothing has changed".

In order to overwrite behavior this I added the following code to my initialize method.

```
initialize: function(attributes, options) {
  ...
  this.changed = attributes;
  this.trigger('change');
  for (attr_name in attributes) {
    this.trigger('change:' + attr_name);
  }
},
```

I trigger **all** change events manually, this is important for me since inheriting models may bind to `change` or `change:attrxy`. But this is not enough, because if I just trigger the events the `changedAttributes()` method would return `false` therefore I also set `this.changed` to the current attributes.